# VBA Outlook - Falha na Operação

Tags: vba, outlook

Fiz uma macro no Outlook 2016 que é executada assim que um e-mail novo chega.

Mas, as vezes, aparece a tela abaixo na hora que o e-mail chega:

[image: Erro de falha na operação, mostrado pelo outlook 2016 ao tentar executar a macro]

E se eu pedir para a pessoa enviar um e-mail novo, exatamente igual ao que fez gerar o erro ou reencaminhar o mesmo e-mail ou ainda se eu, manualmente, mandar executar a regra para as mensagens na caixa de entrada, o erro não aparece novamente.

Essa é a única tela que erro que aparece. Não aparece nenhum erro nas linhas de código, durante a execução (porque nem chega a executar).

Abaixo está o código utilizado:

```
Public Sub enviarListaParceiras(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim strID As String
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim corpoEmail As String
    Dim assunto As String
    Dim de As String
    Dim mensagem As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim nomeEscola As String
    Dim idEscola As Long
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim obj_Connection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim obj_RecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim str_SQL As String
    Dim str_PlanilhaDestino As String
    Dim str_ConnString As String
    Dim str_LinhaInicial As String
    Dim nr_coluna As Integer
    Dim diaUltimaAtualizacao As String
    Dim horaUltimaAtualizacao As String
    Dim horaDoEmail As String
    Dim planilha As Workbook
    Dim nomeArquivo As String
    Dim nomeArquivo2 As String
    Dim dataArquivo As String
    Dim horaArquivo As String
    Dim horaParaPlanilha As String
    Dim dataParaPlanilha As String
    Dim saudacao As String
    Dim nomeEscolaAbreviado As String
    Dim nomeNovaPlanilha As String
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim nomeEnviado As String
    Dim atualizada As Boolean
    Dim grupo As Long
    Dim data, hora As String
    
    If Hour(Now) < 12 Then
        saudacao = "Bom dia!"
    ElseIf Hour(Now) > 11 And Hour(Now) < 18 Then
        saudacao = "Boa tarde!"
    ElseIf Hour(Now) > 17 Then
        saudacao = "Boa noite!"
    End If
    
    strID = Item.EntryID
    Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
    corpoEmail = objMail.Body
    assunto = objMail.Subject
    grupo = CLng(Trim(Mid(assunto, InStr(1, assunto, ")") - 2, 2)))
    If InStr(1, assunto, "#atualizada") > 0 Or InStr(1, assunto, "#Atualizada") > 0 Then
        atualizada = True
    Else
        atualizada = False
    End If
    
    de = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
    If InStr(1, corpoEmail, "De:") <> 0 Then
        email = Mid(corpoEmail, InStr(1, corpoEmail, "De:") + 3, (InStr(1, corpoEmail, "Enviada em:") - 1) - (InStr(1, corpoEmail, "De:") + 3))
        If InStr(1, email, "<") <> 0 Then
            email = Mid(email, InStr(1, email, "<") + 1, ((InStr(1, email, ">") - 1) - InStr(1, email, "<")))
        End If
    End If
    horaDoEmail = objMail.ReceivedTime
    nomeEnviado = objMail.SenderName
    If email = "" Then
        email = de
    End If
    
    
    If atualizada = True Then
        Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
        excelApp.Visible = True
        Set planilha = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("[caminho da pasta]\tentativa 4.0.xlsm")
        With excelApp.Sheets("Principal")
            .Activate
            .Cells(3, "E") = "x"
            .Cells(5, "E") = "x"
        End With
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        excelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        excelApp.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        On Error Resume Next
        excelApp.Run "'tentativa 4.0.xlsm'!principal"
        excelApp.Workbooks("tentativa 4.0.xlsm").Activate
        nomeNovaPlanilha = excelApp.Workbooks("tentativa 4.0.xlsm").Sheets("Principal").Cells(1, "M")
        excelApp.Workbooks("tentativa 4.0.xlsm").Save
        excelApp.Workbooks("tentativa 4.0.xlsm").Close
        excelApp.Quit
        nomeArquivo = ListaArquivos("[caminho da pasta]\Atual")
        Kill ("[caminho da pasta]\Atual\" & nomeArquivo)
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        Call FSO.CopyFile("[caminho da pasta]/" & nomeNovaPlanilha, "[caminho da pasta]/Atual/")
        nomeArquivo = ListaArquivos("[caminho da pasta]\Atual")
        data = Mid(nomeArquivo, 46, InStr(46, nomeArquivo, "_") - 46)
        hora = Mid(nomeArquivo, InStr(46, nomeArquivo, "_") + 1, InStr(1, nomeArquivo, ".") - InStr(46, nomeArquivo, "_"))
        hora = Left(hora, Len(hora) - 1)
        
        Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        excelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        excelApp.Visible = True
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open ("[caminho da pasta]\Geração_ListaEspera_PARCEIRAS_2021_v2.6 - OUTLOOK.xlsm")
        excelApp.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Select
        DoEvents
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Cells(grupo + 7, "A") = "x"
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Cells(4, "A") = data
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Cells(5, "A") = hora
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Cells(1, "C") = nomeArquivo
        excelApp.Run ("chamarMetodos")
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        
        texto = saudacao & "<br><br>Segue lista de espera da unidade parceira solicitada.<br><br>"
        nomeArquivo = ListaArquivos("[caminho da pasta]\enviar")
        
        Call encaminharEmailParceira(objMail, email, texto, "[caminho da pasta]\enviar\" & nomeArquivo)
        
        Kill ("[caminho da pasta]\enviar\" & nomeArquivo)
        
        excelApp.Quit
        Set objMail = Nothing
        Set excelApp = Nothing
        nomeEscola = ""
        idEscola = 0
        email = ""
    Else
        nomeArquivo = ListaArquivos("[caminho da pasta]\Atual")
        data = Mid(nomeArquivo, 46, InStr(46, nomeArquivo, "_") - 46)
        hora = Mid(nomeArquivo, InStr(46, nomeArquivo, "_") + 1, InStr(1, nomeArquivo, ".") - InStr(46, nomeArquivo, "_"))
        hora = Left(hora, Len(hora) - 1)
        
        Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        excelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        excelApp.Visible = True
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open ("[caminho da pasta]\Geração_ListaEspera_PARCEIRAS_2021_v2.6 - OUTLOOK.xlsm")
        excelApp.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Select
        DoEvents
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Cells(grupo + 7, "A") = "x"
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Cells(4, "A") = data
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Cells(5, "A") = hora
        excelApp.Sheets("Seleção Escolas").Cells(1, "C") = nomeArquivo
        excelApp.Run ("chamarMetodos")
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        
        texto = saudacao & "<br><br>Segue lista de espera da unidade parceira solicitada.<br><br>"
        nomeArquivo = ListaArquivos("[caminho da pasta]\enviar")
        
        Call encaminharEmailParceira(objMail, email, texto, "[caminho da pasta]\enviar\" & nomeArquivo)
        
        Kill ("[caminho da pasta]\enviar\" & nomeArquivo)
        
        excelApp.Quit
        Set objMail = Nothing
        Set excelApp = Nothing
        nomeEscola = ""
        idEscola = 0
        email = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

A configuração da regra está na imagem a seguir:
[image: Configuração da regra no outlook 2016]

Eu realmente não tenho ideia do que pode estar ocasionando esse erro.

Comment: Pô, votar negativo sem comentar o porquê, não me ajuda a melhorar a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricardo, blz!
Recomendo que sempre use um log para identificar o erro que está sendo gerado, se não solicitado não será informado, vou colocar abaixo como deve fazer.
1º logo após o inicio:
Public Sub enviarListaParceiras(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
insira:

```
On Error Goto Err_Control
```

2º No final das Sub ou Functions, insira:

```
Err_Control:    
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Call LogErr("Insira_aqui_o_nome_que_quiser, identifica Sub or function", Err.Number, Err.Description)
    End If
```

Abaixo a Function que grava em um arquivo txt os erros aonde é executado o código, uso isso para Excel, não testei no Outlook, pode ser comentado para que não execute, mas pelo menos a função MsgBox Err.Description, irá informar o erro, e você pode incrementar exibindo o número do erro:

> MsgBox "Descrição erro:" & Err.Description & " Número erro:" & Err.Number.

pode ser que ajude, basta remover o "Call LogErr" para não acionar o arquivo Log.

```
Public Function LogErr(Modulo As String, ErrNumber As Long, ErrDescription As String)
On Error Resume Next
Dim strFile_Path As String
strFile_Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "_" & "log_file.txt"
    Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
    Write #1, Now() & " | Módulo: " & Modulo & " | Err_Number: " & ErrNumber & " | Err_Description: " & ErrDescription & " | Máquina: " & Environ$("computername") & " | User: " & Application.UserName
    Close #1
End Function
```

Para descobrir seus locais de "Application.ActiveWorkbook.path" use o debug, no seu caso remova a continuação "ActiveWorkbook.Name" este uso muito para Excel, tente adaptar para identificar melhor o que está causando seu erro, espero que ajude. Tente fazer testes com você mesmo enviando os emails, faça testes em massa e depois adapte para uso como deseja.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sugestão, Julio. Vou testar com certeza. Quando tiver mais informações sobre o erro, ajeitarei a pergunta.

Comment: Legal, informe o número do erro, nem sempre é possível rodar debugando deve ser o seu caso e realmente fica difícil identificar o que causa "falha na operação" que é a descrição do erro, em qual operação? Você pode colocar no Err_Control: stop e fazer F5 para ver aonde este erro é gerado no código.

Comment: Eu deixei apenas com a geração do arquivo de log, sem o MsgBox e após diversos testes, infelizmente, quando essa janela de erro aparece, o arquivo de log não é gerado.

Comment: Usa o msgbox então, pra tentar identificar onde é gerado o erro, como comentei acima. Nem tudo Outlook informa o erro, simplesmente sai ao dar erro, remove o "On erro resume next." Coloca um stop lá na chamada do erro, If err.number <>0 then stop, e veja aonde está o erro!

Comment: Teste se o arquivo log é gerado por outro erro qualquer, crie um erro qualquer e teste para vê se ele funciona, aonde é gerado este arquivo, comigo sempre funcionou mas Outlook é diferente sim, e posso tá repassando algo que ele não faz. Não sei

Comment: O arquivo é gerado sim. Todas as vezes que eu forcei um erro durante a execução, ele gera. O que parece, é que esse erro que aparece a tela de falha na operação acontece antes de executar a macro

Comment: Agora que notei o on error resume next no seu código. Remova isso para que ele vá ao "on erro goto Err_Control:" aí sim ele i poderá registrar algum erro que antes ele tentava reexecutar, e ao reexecutar ele limpar o err.number, sem isso talvez descubra o erro.

Comment: Parece ser erro ao criar o excelApp e colocar "excelApp.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        On Error Resume Next" não ajuda, na verdade tenta sobrepor o erro e daí não executa. Verifique está parte do código.

Comment: Puts, é mesmo. Você tem razão. O olho está tão viciado, de tanto rever o código, que nem enxergava mais o 'On error resume next'. Comentei ele.